# jQuery image src change by radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code but why when i click on any radio button the image src doesn't change?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Toggle Images using RadioButtons</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input:radio[name=style]").change(function() {
                if (this.value == "tuxedo"){
                        var style = 'tuxedo';
                } else {
                        var style = 'classic' ;                  
                }
            });
            $("input:radio[name=breast]").change(function() {
              if (this.value == "double"){
                        var breast = 'double';
                } else {
                        var breast = 'single' ;                  
                }
            });
            $("input:radio[name=buttons]").change(function() {
            if (this.value == "4"){
                        var buttons = '4';
           } else if (this.value == "3"){
                        var buttons = '3';
            } else if (this.value == "2"){
                        var buttons = '2';
                } else {
                        var buttons = '1' ;                  
                }
            });
       
                          $("#imgDef").attr(
                        'src', 'http://127.0.0.1/2/suits/'+ style +'/'+ breast +'/'+ buttons +'.jpg'                   
                    );
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Style:<br />
<label><input name="style" type="radio" value="classic" />Classic</label><br />
<label><input name="style" type="radio" value="tuxedo" />Tuxedo</label><br />
<br /><br />
Breast:<br />
<label><input name="breast" type="radio" value="single" />Single</label><br />
<label><input name="breast" type="radio" value="double" />Double</label><br />
Buttons:<br />
<label><input name="buttons" type="radio" value="1" />1</label><br />
<label><input name="buttons" type="radio" value="2" />2</label><br />
<label><input name="buttons" type="radio" value="3" />3</label><br />
<label><input name="buttons" type="radio" value="4" />4</label><br />
<img id="imgDef" src="http://127.0.0.1/2/suits/classic/single/1.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `style`, `buttons`, and `breast` are all out of scope when you update the `src` attribute. Declare them in the same scope as `$("#imgDef").attr()` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working example. http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/FsSz6/
 if you  want to change the image src only when all the 3 sections are selected, you may need to add  a check for undefined in each variable before setting the img src

```
var style,breast,buttons;

$("input:radio[name=style]").change(function() {

                if (this.value == "tuxedo"){
                         style = 'tuxedo';
                } else {
                         style = 'classic' ;                  
                }
    loadImage();
            });
            $("input:radio[name=breast]").change(function() {
              if (this.value == "double"){
                         breast = 'double';
                } else {
                         breast = 'single' ;                  
                }
                 loadImage();
            });
            $("input:radio[name=buttons]").change(function() {
            if (this.value == "4"){
                         buttons = '4';
           } else if (this.value == "3"){
                         buttons = '3';
            } else if (this.value == "2"){
                         buttons = '2';
                } else {
                         buttons = '1' ;                  
                }
                 loadImage();
            });
function  loadImage(){
    alert('http://127.0.0.1/2/suits/'+ style +'/'+ breast +'/'+ buttons +'.jpg');
                          $("#imgDef").attr(
                        'src', 'http://127.0.0.1/2/suits/'+ style +'/'+ breast +'/'+ buttons +'.jpg'                   
                    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're defining style, breast and buttons in scope of each function bound to .change event on your input fields. They won't be accessible outside of those functions. Declare them outside of your functions then set them inside your input change functions.

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var style, breast, buttons;
        $("input:radio[name=style]").change(function() {
            if (this.value == "tuxedo"){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("input:radio[name=buttons]").change(function() {
               var buttons;

                if (this.value == "4"){
                            buttons = '4';
               } else if (this.value == "3"){
                            buttons = '3';
                } else if (this.value == "2"){
                            buttons = '2';
                    } else {
                            buttons = '1' ;                  
                    }
                });
```

declare like this..hope it works for you..

you better to get the value of checked radio button like this

**`$('input:radio[name=buttons]:checked').val();`**

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your variables at the beginning of your "ready" handler:
   `$(document).ready(function() {
       var style;
       var breast;
       var buttons;
       ...`
2. Don't use var inside conditional statements. Just set the value:
   `if (this.value == "tuxedo"){
       style = 'tuxedo';
       ....`
3. Call the code which changes src attribute at the end of your "change" handlers. You have to call it three times.